# How to get an array with true/false values after comparing 2 arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to generate array as a result of comparison 2 arrays as:

```
a = %w{a b a e}
b = %w{c d a e}
```

After comparing it should give result as:

```
c = [false, false, true, true]
```

Is there any ruby way which is better than doing a `for` loop because I have to do this comparison with a lot of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way?

```
a.zip(b).map { |a, b| a == b }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uglier, but just to show an alternative:

```
a.map.with_index { |aa, i| aa == b[i] }
```